# how to exit the application on back press from main activity?

Tags: android

i have main activity and login screen..on pressing login button in main activity login screen will be displayed...i have a separate back button on login screen on pressing that button it goes back to main Activity...now if i back press in Main Activity i want to close the application..How can i do that?

i have written a code

```
public void onBackPressed() {
finsh()
}
```

but this is working when i first open main activity and back press it closes the app...but if i press login button...go to login screen and come back to main activity and back press it comes back to login screen..
please help

Comment: when starting MainActivity from Login Activity also call finish(); after startActivity(intent);

Comment: You need to `finish` your login `Activity` on the press of the `separate back button on login screen`. Have you done that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add this to your login activity

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use 
[FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) when going to MainActivity From Login..

it clears top tasks and prevents user to go back to previous `Activities`..

You Can Write Intent Like This..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); // clears all previous activities task
    finish(); // destroy current activity..
    startActivity(intent); // starts new activity
```

And if you want to EXIT application directly from `**MainActivity**` use **Finish()** Method..

override `OnBackPressed()` Function in **MainActivity.java**...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```